# Getting the title of youtube video in pytube3?

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to build an app to download YouTube videos in python using *pytube3*.
But I am unable to retrieve the title of the video.
Here goes my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube(link)
print(yt.title)
```

No matter whatever is the link I always get the title returned as `YouTube` instead of title of the video.
Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: You may not be doing anything wrong - quite often I get "YouTube", or the actual title, depending on which video I am downloading. Some of them, in other words, have the title set properly, and others don't.

Comment: same observation, sometimes the title is not available

Answer (score 7):

try this instead

```
yt.streams[0].title
```

or

```
yt.streams[0].default_filename
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me either, I think it's a problem related to the package and hoping will be solved in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

try:
`yt.title`

output:
`Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)`

(or the video name of the link you entered and no its not a rickroll, I was listening to this while scrolling through StackOverFlow).

Answer (score 3):

Try: `print(yt._title)`
It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

pytube3 is no longer being maintained and so this bug will probably not be fixed on this library. [pytubex](https://github.com/H4KKR/pytubeX/) is a version of pytube that is still being maintained and has fixed this and many other bugs.

Answer (score 1):

`yt.title` should do the work. Still working btw if someone it's looking for this in 2023