# Pytube3 - YouTube.title is returning 'YouTube' instead of the expected title

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

when I try to download a video its titled as 'YouTube' why? and how do I fix it?.

```
import pytube
  
yt = pytube.YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKQLKf3dS1Y')
vid = yt.streams.first()

# returns 'YouTube'
print(vid.title)

print('downloading..')

# the title of the video is 'YouTube'
vid.download(r'C:\Users\sruls\OneDrive\Desktop\yt-dl')

print('download complete')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vid.download() has a second parameter which you can make the name of the video.

```
vid.download(r'C:\Users\sruls\OneDrive\Desktop', vid.title) # the first parameter is the directory(the folder)
```

Comment: this would let me manually type in the name but when I type it out the way you do I still get  the title 'YouTube' for every video

Comment: I've had a similar problem. The same URL seems to randomly return the correct title or else "YouTube" as the title. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652157/getting-the-title-of-youtube-video-in-pytube3?rq=1)  have reported the same problem.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/632) in the repository posts code that is said to solve the problem, which stems from a timing issue is fetching the information.

Comment: thanks the solution worked it still takes seven or so loops before it gets the title right but that's probably because of my internet

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with pytube3, I recommend switching over to [pytubex](https://github.com/H4KKR/pytubeX/) which fixes this bug. pytube3 is no longer being maintained so I'd recommend switching over to pytubex since it is being maintained.